# The APK that is compiled by the mm command can not read the contents of the SD card

Tags: android, file, build, exists

```
File settingFile = new File(getString(R.string.settingFile));
Log.d("debug",settingFile.toString());
if(settingFile.exists()){
    Log.d("debug","exists");
} else {
    Log.d("debug","not exists");
}
```

The APK that is compiled by Eclipse can output `exists`, but by when compile with the mm command it outputs `not exists`.
Can you help me?